# How can I change the cursor color in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 8, with the theme midnight whose background is black. This makes it really difficult to distinguish the cursor from the background.I've tried going to preferences of both, my Mac and Xcode, but I cannot change it. I don't want to change the theme. What can I do?

Comment: https://blog.michaelyin.info/2015/04/15/how-to-make-mac-os-x-cursor-more-visible/

Answer (score 1):

Change the cursor color here? Or would that be considered as changing the theme? Unless you want to actually change your mac's cursor, check out what @Dominik posted.

[image: Xcode Image]

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work. What I want to change is the i-beam.